# Is there any way to access the information of the groups used in the view within hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter()?

Tags: views

Is there any way to access the information of the groups used in the view within `hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter`?

I am trying to find them within the view element:
`$form_state->getStorage()['view']` or `$form_state->getStorage()['view']->storage`.